# Image Resize in Symfony 2.8

Tags: symfony

i am using Symfony 2.8 version for my site. i need to resize image in all pages can any one help me to solve this issue.

I am using gregwar/image but not getting idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle
You can the size of your image in your config.yml and then, liip generate your images automatically ;)